# How do I use su to reinstall app itself in Android

Tags: android, su

I have an app, I want the app can be updated byitself. The steps is:

1、the app get the update notification, then download the latest APK file into the storage
2、the app uses the Runtime.getRuntime().exec('su') to fork a process with root permission
3、the app let the process run command 'pm install -rf /storage/emulated/0/latest.apk && am start -n xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xxx', which means reinstall the app itself and launch it after reinstalled

these codes works well in some android version.

In a specific android version rom, the pm install command is executed as expected, but the commands left are not executed.

It seems that the pm install command killed the app process, and the su process is also killed at the same time which leads the left command not executed.

As far as I know from the Google Android website, the Runtime.getRuntime() will fork a subprocess, which will be executed no matter the app process is alive or not.

So, I need a help, what's wrong with this situation?

Many thanks.